# "Service failed to start, CLSID for Type MapServer is not registered" Enterprise SOE

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, .net, arcgis-enterprise, server-object-extension

In ArcGIS Server Manager, I'm trying to add an SOE for our Enterprise env based on this walkthrough: https://developers.arcgis.com/enterprise-sdk/guide/net/walkthrough-for-rest-soes-net/

However whenever I try to start the service in Server Manager, I get this error message:

"Service failed to start
veg.MapServer:

CLSID for Type MapServer is not registered"

I can't find any info on this issue, does anyone have an idea? We're running version 11.1 of Enterprise.

EDIT: I get the impression this is happening because I'm building my SOE on a different machine than the one the server is running on, but that's just an assumption. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server machine right now.